# Visualforce : Dynamically displaying fields based on controller variable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom object C.

It has two fields `F1__c` and `F2__c`.

In my controller there is a String `s`.

The `s` contains "`F1__c`"

Will it be possible for me to display this field whose API name is contained in the variable `s` ?

```
public xyzcontroller 
{

public String s{get;set;}

public xyzcontroller()
{

s = "F1__c";

}


}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried following Vamsi's answer but no luck.

Here is my actual VF/Controller

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="TestXXXController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">


    <apex:form id="theform">
        <h2>Questions</h2>


        <apex:outputField value="{!pr.get(varstr)}"/>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestXXXController {

    public XXX__c pr{get;set;}

    public String varstr{get;set;}


    public TestXXXController()
    {
        init();
    }



    public void init()
    {

        XXX__c p = new XXX__c();
        String queryStr = 'Select '+CommonUsedClass.sObjectGetAllFields(p).trim()+' FROM XXX__c LIMIT 1';
        List<XXX__c> plist = new List<XXX__c>();
        plist = Database.query(queryStr);

        pr = plist[0];

        System.debug('p == > '+ pr);

        varstr = 'Schema.XXX__c.Name';


    }







    }
```

The above VF page gives me compile error as shown below

```
Could not resolve field 'get(varstr)' from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!pr.get(varstr)}' in page TestXXX1
```

Comment: @Vamsi - Unfortunately the answer you provided does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VF PAGE:**

```
<apex:page controller="SampleApex">
    FirstName : {!cObj['FirstName']}
     <br/>
    LastName : {!cObj[VarStr]}
</apex:page>
```

**Controller :**

```
public class SampleApex {

    public Contact cObj {get;set;}
    String varStr;
    public SampleApex () {
        cObj = new Contact (FirstName ='JAck', LastName='Cool');

        varStr = 'LastName';        
    }

    public String getVarStr () {
       return varStr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to display the value of a field in your visualforce page, You can use [sObject.get(fiedName)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) in `apex:outputField` to pass in the fieldName dynamically and get the value displayed.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!YourObject.get(YourFieldNameVariable)}"/>
```